# Access all dictionary values in a 2d dictionary - Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a 2d dictionary:

```
errorDict[TS][NT]
```

TS has values ranging from 1,10. and NT has values ranging from 1,5.

I want to extract all the data for one value, NT=5, while maintaining the TS entries.

So in psuedo code it would looks like this:

```
errorDict[All][5]
```

All the solutions I can find involve iterating to create a new dictionary. Surely there is a better way?

Comment: can you give a sample of `errorDict` object?

Comment: errorDict[1][5] = [0.5, 0.4, 0.44, 0.32, 0.43], errorDict[2][5] = [0.9, 0.23, 0.3, 0.4, 0.78]. And so on.